Source database does not show in drop down ever after selecting it vanishes
I am trying to compare the schema of DEV server to GIT project. When i connect to source DB it does not show in the dropdown after selection it simply vanishes. This is not allowing me to do schema comparison.
Steps performed
1- Tried restarting the visual studio.
2- Tried connecting to database from server explorer window.
3- Tried removing the history of server and connect new but still vanishes.
Screenshot attached to show where its not showing source.
Am i missing something in the process . Do we have any fix for this issue.
